# i want to show set to array which is not empty, if search hits empty array then count upto 10 still empty array then close array and continue

Tags: php, zend-framework

in the following array i want to show from array[0] to array[2] is pack1, array[5] to array[10] pack2, array[10] to array[12] is pack3 pack4 starts from array[14]. (if empty array is above 2 then close the pack and start another pack)

```
array
(
 [0] => array
    (
     [id] => 1
     [num] => 980909
    )

 [1] => array
    (
     [id] => 2
     [num] => 090909
    )

 [2] => array
    (
     [id] => 3
     [num] => 909
    )

 [3] => array
    (
    )
 [4] => array
    (
    )
 [5] => array
    (
     [id] => 6
     [num] => 6565
    )
 [6] => array
    (
     [id] => 7
     [num] => 6565
    )
 [7] => array
    (
     [id] => 8
     [num] => 65
    )
 [8] => array
    (
    ) 
 [9] => array
    (
     [id] => 10
     [num] => 665
    )
 [10] => array
    (
     [id] => 11
     [num] => 600
    )
 [11] => array
    (
    ) 
 [12] => array
    (
    ) 
 [13] => array
    (
    ) 
 [14] => array
    (
     [id] => 15
     [num] => 700
    )
```

Comment: What's the logic behind?

Comment: number of pages viewed, if no views then it will empty array

Comment: Logic for the packs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$datas = array(); 
$empcount = 10; $emp = $dIndex = 0;

for($i=0;$i
  if( $emp >= $empcount)  {  $dIndex++; $emp = 0; }   $datas[$dIndex][] = $finaldata[$i];  }